# Ordering and set theory problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be a set. Let $F$ is the collection of all functions  $h: X\to X$, $E$ the collection of all the equivalent relations on $X$, and $P$ the collection of all   partial orderings on $X$.

Find $F\cap E\cap P$. 
Why doing this intersection makes sense? (i.e why isn't the intersection empty?)

Comment: Why wouldn’t it make sense? They’re sets... you can intersect them. Do you mean why isn’t the intersection obviously empty? In that case note that all three of these consist of binary relations on $X$ satisfying certain properties.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, that's what I meant, maybe I wasn't clear enough,sorry

Comment: The identity function on $X$ is an element of all three (assuming partial order means non-strict partial order).

Comment: Adding to spaceisdarkgreen's comment, you can even prove something stronger. That the identity function on $X$, is the only element of the intersection.

Comment: In case you confusion isn't completely cleared up by spaceisdarkgreen's first comment, Note that functions, equivalence relations, and partial orderings can each be considered as subsets of $X^2 = X \times X$. So $F,E,P$ themselves are subsets of the powerset $\mathscr P(X^2)$.